# Cumsum reset at NaN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cumsum

If I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` named `ts` of either 1's or NaN's like this:

```
3382   NaN
3381   NaN
...
3369   NaN
3368   NaN
...
15     1
10   NaN
11     1
12     1
13     1
9    NaN
8    NaN
7    NaN
6    NaN
3    NaN
4      1
5      1
2    NaN
1    NaN
0    NaN
```

I would like to calculate cumsum of this serie but it should be reset (set to zero) at the location of the NaNs like below:

```
3382   0
3381   0
...
3369   0
3368   0
...
15     1
10     0
11     1
12     2
13     3
9      0
8      0
7      0
6      0
3      0
4      1
5      2
2      0
1      0
0      0
```

Ideally I would like to have a vectorized solution !

I ever see a similar question with Matlab : 
[Matlab cumsum reset at NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995399/matlab-cumsum-reset-at-nan)

but I don't know how to translate this line `d = diff([0 c(n)]);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple Numpy translation of your Matlab code is this:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1., 1., 1., np.nan, 1., 1., 1., 1., np.nan, 1.])
n = np.isnan(v)
a = ~n
c = np.cumsum(a)
d = np.diff(np.concatenate(([0.], c[n])))
v[n] = -d
np.cumsum(v)
```

Executing this code returns the result `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  1.])`. This solution will only be as valid as the original one, but maybe it will help you come up with something better if it isn't sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: it wouldn't work with: v = np.array([1., 2., 4., np.nan, 1., 3., 1., 3., np.nan, 1.])

Comment: If you change `a = ~n` to `a = np.nan_to_num(v)`, it also works for v with values other than 1.

Answer (score 14):

Even more pandas-onic way to do it:

```
v = pd.Series([1., 3., 1., np.nan, 1., 1., 1., 1., np.nan, 1.])
cumsum = v.cumsum().fillna(method='pad')
reset = -cumsum[v.isnull()].diff().fillna(cumsum)
result = v.where(v.notnull(), reset).cumsum()
```

Contrary to the matlab code, this also works for values different from 1.

Comment: This is the best answer of the lot. If you want to understand how it works, just add one more line at the end: `print(pd.DataFrame({'v': v, 'cum': cumsum, 'reset': reset, 'result': result}))`, and run this code.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a slightly more pandas-onic way to do it:

```
v = Series([1, 1, 1, nan, 1, 1, 1, 1, nan, 1], dtype=float)
n = v.isnull()
a = ~n
c = a.cumsum()
index = c[n].index  # need the index for reconstruction after the np.diff
d = Series(np.diff(np.hstack(([0.], c[n]))), index=index)
v[n] = -d
result = v.cumsum()
```

Note that either of these requires that you're using `pandas` at  least at [`9da899b`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/9da899ba3d1099d7456adb32ea129547f152dee8) or newer. If you aren't then you can cast the `bool` `dtype` to an `int64` or `float64` `dtype`:

```
v = Series([1, 1, 1, nan, 1, 1, 1, 1, nan, 1], dtype=float)
n = v.isnull()
a = ~n
c = a.astype(float).cumsum()
index = c[n].index  # need the index for reconstruction after the np.diff
d = Series(np.diff(np.hstack(([0.], c[n]))), index=index)
v[n] = -d
result = v.cumsum()
```

Comment: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` for `ts.notnull.cumsum()` on pandas 0.12. I'm not sure why this would occur for a boolean series..

Comment: That should've been fixed by [`9da899b`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/9da899ba3d1099d7456adb32ea129547f152dee8)

Comment: @Closed Make sure you're up to date and let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Closed I've updated my answer for usage pre [`9da899b`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/9da899ba3d1099d7456adb32ea129547f152dee8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @nosuchthingasstars 's answer is marked as solving this issue... but I also like your answer! You should write `ts = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=1000), dtype=float)`

Comment: I think there is a mistake `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#ts = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=1000), dtype=float)
#ts[np.random.rand(len(ts)) > 0.5] = np.nan
ts = pd.Series([1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,1])

valid = ts.notnull()
#c = valid.cumsum() # with pd>=0.12
c = valid.astype(int).cumsum() # because of Pandas bug with bool and cumsum for pd<0.12
d = c.diff().fillna(0)
ts[~valid] = d` because `ts= 1 1 1 0 0 1 1` it should output `1 2 3 0 0 1 2`

Comment: @working4coins I've updated my answer to give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see, it's very close from nosuchthingasstars solution.

Comment: Will that answer maintain the index?

Answer (score 6):

If you can accept a similar boolean Series `b`, try

```
(b.cumsum() - b.cumsum().where(~b).fillna(method='pad').fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

Starting from your Series `ts`, either `b = (ts == 1)` or `b = ~ts.isnull()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `expanding().apply` and `replace` with `method='backfill'`

```
reset_at = 0

ts.expanding().apply(
    lambda s:
        s[
            (s != reset_at).replace(True, method='backfill')
        ].sum()
).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
cond = ts.isnull()
groups = (cond != cond.shift()).cumsum()
result = ts.groupby(groups).apply(lambda x: x.cumsum()).fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
result.index = result.index.get_level_values(1)
```

or more simplified:

```
cond = ts.isnull()
groups = (cond != cond.shift()).cumsum()
result = ts.groupby(groups).agg('cumsum').fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
```

It works by first checking whether each value matches the condition of group delimiter (`cond`). Later it compares this condition with the previous one to mark which element starts a new group (`cond != cond.shift()`), the `cumsum` there assigns a new group value to each group.

After that it just group by the group number and perform the desired operation (`cumsum`) inside each group. I like this way because it clearly delimits the condition for the group delimiters and the the operation to perform.