# Cumulative counts in NumPy without iteration

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like so:

```
a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.6, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
```

I'd like to have a running counter of **instances of 1.0** that **resets when it encounters a 0.0**, so the result would be:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

My initial thought was to use something like b = np.cumsum(a[a==1.0]), but I don't know how to (1) modify this to reset at zeros or (2) quite how to structure it so the output array is the same shape as the input array.  Any ideas how to do this without iteration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you could do something like

```
def rcount(a):
    without_reset = (a == 1).cumsum()
    reset_at = (a == 0)
    overcount = np.maximum.accumulate(without_reset * reset_at)
    result = without_reset - overcount
    return result
```

which gives me

```
>>> a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.6, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
>>> rcount(a)
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

This works because we can use the cumulative maximum to figure out the "overcount":

```
>>> without_reset * reset_at
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0])
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(without_reset * reset_at)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4])
```

---

Sanity testing:

```
def manual(arr):
    out = []
    count = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x == 1:
            count += 1
        if x == 0:
            count = 0
        out.append(count)
    return out

def test():
    for w in [1, 2, 10, 10**4]:
        for trial in range(100):
            for vals in [0,1],[0,1,2]:
                b = np.random.choice(vals, size=w)
                assert (rcount(b) == manual(b)).all()
    print("hooray!")
```

and then

```
>>> test()
hooray!
```

Comment: Nicely done! FYI, the accepted answer to this question solves a nearly identical problem, but also works if some of the values being accumulated are negative. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196811/cumsum-reset-at-nan