# Numpy index a 1D array to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Below is code with the functionality I want on some simple sample data.  Basically I binned data using [np.digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize), and then I computed a column index based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027288/cumulative-counts-in-numpy-without-iteration).  bin_idx is known to never decrease in case that helps.  How can I index to get the 2D array without an explicit loop?  One complication is that the number of values in each row/bin varies.  I will later do different statistics on each bin/row, max just being an example.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
bin_idx = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
col_idx = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2])

binned = np.ones((bin_idx[-1]+1, np.max(col_idx)+1)) * np.nan
for i in range(len(x)):
    binned[bin_idx[i], col_idx[i]] = x[i]
print(binned)
row_max = np.nanmax(binned, 1)
print(row_max)
```

Comment: Aside: if you're working with data, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) might be more natural than working with bare numpy; here, you're basically reimplementing something like `df.pivot(1,2,0).max(axis=1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy indexing allows you to pass sequences as indices. Also check out Numpy's [full](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) method used below to create the `binned` array.

```
binned = np.full((bin_idx[-1]+1, np.max(col_idx)+1), np.nan)
binned[bin_idx, col_idx] = x
```