# In Python Pandas using cumsum with groupby and reset of cumsum when value is 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, cumsum

I'm rather new at python.
I try to have a cumulative sum for each client to see the consequential months of inactivity (flag: 1 or 0). The cumulative sum of the 1's need therefore to be reset when we have a 0. The reset need to happen as well when we have a new client. See below with example where a is the column of clients and b are the dates.

After some research, I found the question 'Cumsum reset at NaN' and 'In Python Pandas using cumsum with groupby'. I assume that I kind of need to put them together. 
Adapting the code of 'Cumsum reset at NaN' to the reset towards 0, is successful:

```
cumsum = v.cumsum().fillna(method='pad')
reset = -cumsum[v.isnull() !=0].diff().fillna(cumsum)
result = v.where(v.notnull(), reset).cumsum()
```

However, I don't succeed at adding a groupby. My count just goes on...

So, a dataset would be like this: 
import pandas as pd

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                    'b' : [1/15,2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15,6/15,1/15,2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15,6/15], 
                    'c' : [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]})
```

this should result in a dataframe with the columns a, b, c and d with

```
'd' : [1,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4]
```

Please note that I have a very large dataset, so calculation time is really important.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Have you looked at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196811/cumsum-reset-at-nan

Answer (score 6):

Use [`groupby.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) after finding contiguous values in the groups. Then [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the integer counting upto each contiguous value and add 1 later.

Multiply with the original row to create the AND logic cancelling all zeros and only considering positive values.

```
df['d'] = df.groupby('a')['c']                                                            \
            .apply(lambda x: x * (x.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1))

print(df['d'])

0     1
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     2
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     0
10    1
11    2
12    3
13    4
Name: d, dtype: int64
```

---

Another way of doing would be to apply a function after [`series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) on the groupby object which basically computes values on the series starting from the first index upto that current index.

Use `reduce` later to apply function of two args cumulatively to the items of iterable so as to reduce it to a single value.

```
from functools import reduce

df.groupby('a')['c'].expanding()                                         \
  .apply(lambda i: reduce(lambda x, y: x+1 if y==1 else 0, i, 0))

a    
1  0     1.0
   1     0.0
   2     1.0
   3     0.0
   4     1.0
   5     2.0
   6     0.0
2  7     1.0
   8     2.0
   9     0.0
   10    1.0
   11    2.0
   12    3.0
   13    4.0
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

**Timings:**

```
%%timeit
df.groupby('a')['c'].apply(lambda x: x * (x.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.groupby('a')['c'].expanding().apply(lambda s: reduce(lambda x, y: x+1 if y==1 else 0, s, 0))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need custom function with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
#change row with index 6 to 1 for better testing
df =  pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                    'b' : [1/15,2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15,6/15,1/15,2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15,6/15,7/15,8/15], 
                    'c' : [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
                    'd' : [1,0,1,0,1,2,3,1,2,0,1,2,3,4]})

print (df)
    a         b  c  d
0   1  0.066667  1  1
1   1  0.133333  0  0
2   1  0.200000  1  1
3   1  0.266667  0  0
4   1  0.333333  1  1
5   1  0.400000  1  2
6   1  0.066667  1  3
7   2  0.133333  1  1
8   2  0.200000  1  2
9   2  0.266667  0  0
10  2  0.333333  1  1
11  2  0.400000  1  2
12  2  0.466667  1  3
13  2  0.533333  1  4
```

```
def f(x):
    x.ix[x.c == 1, 'e'] = 1
    a = x.e.notnull()
    x.e = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
    return (x)

print (df.groupby('a').apply(f))
    a         b  c  d  e
0   1  0.066667  1  1  1
1   1  0.133333  0  0  0
2   1  0.200000  1  1  1
3   1  0.266667  0  0  0
4   1  0.333333  1  1  1
5   1  0.400000  1  2  2
6   1  0.066667  1  3  3
7   2  0.133333  1  1  1
8   2  0.200000  1  2  2
9   2  0.266667  0  0  0
10  2  0.333333  1  1  1
11  2  0.400000  1  2  2
12  2  0.466667  1  3  3
13  2  0.533333  1  4  4
```