# pandas use cumsum over columns but reset count

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741136/in-python-pandas-using-cumsum-with-groupby-and-reset-of-cumsum-when-value-is-0) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196811/cumsum-reset-at-nan/) post have gotten me close, but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

I have a df that looks like:

```
     2017-04-03    2017-04-04    2017-04-05    2017-04-06
id                                                                         
0           0.0        active           0.0           0.0   
1           0.0        active           0.0        active   
2           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
```

I want to count the zeros across each row and put them into a string to code the data, but the count needs to reset whenever there aren't consecutive zeros.

For the above df, the output df would look like:

```
     2017-04-03    2017-04-04    2017-04-05    2017-04-06
id                                                                         
0    inactive_1        active    inactive_1    inactive_2   
1    inactive_1        active    inactive_1        active   
2    inactive_1    inactive_2    inactive_3    inactive_4
```

this function gets me very close, but doesn't account for reseting the cumsum, it just sums for all instances of zero in the row.

```
def inactive(s):
     np.where(s == 0, 'inactive_' + (s.eq(0).cumsum()).astype(str), s)

df.apply(inactive, 1)
```

Comment: What is number of index and number of columns in real data?

Comment: ~100,000 rows by ~300 columns.  @coldspeed's solution below works well

Comment: @Matt cheers. You can upvote all answers, even if you can accept just one.

Comment: I compare solutions and with my sample data and `100000, 300` rows, columns - `cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ` solution is `3.5` times slowier as `me` ;), check [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863123/2901002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little roundabout, but this can be done by applying a `groupby` operation on each row, and then using `np.where` to selectively apply your values to the original.

```
def f(x):
    return x.groupby(x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

i = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
j = 'inactive_' + i.apply(f, axis=1).astype(str)

df[:] = np.where(i.ne(0), df.values, j)

df

    2017-04-03  2017-04-04  2017-04-05  2017-04-06
id                                                
0   inactive_1      active  inactive_1  inactive_2
1   inactive_1      active  inactive_1      active
2   inactive_1  inactive_2  inactive_3  inactive_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#convert to numeric, NaNs for non numeric
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#count consecutive values with reset
a = df1 == 0
b = a.cumsum(axis=1)
c = b-b.where(~a, axis=1).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

print (c)
    2017-04-03  2017-04-04  2017-04-05  2017-04-06
id                                                
0            1           0           1           2
1            1           0           1           0
2            1           2           3           4


#replace by mask 
df = df.mask(c != 0, 'inactive_' + c.astype(str))
print (df)
    2017-04-03  2017-04-04  2017-04-05  2017-04-06
id                                                
0   inactive_1      active  inactive_1  inactive_2
1   inactive_1      active  inactive_1      active
2   inactive_1  inactive_2  inactive_3  inactive_4
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(425)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 'active'], size=(100000, 300)))

In [4]: %timeit (jez(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 40s per loop

In [5]: %timeit col(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 5min 54s per loop
```

---

```
def jez(df):
    df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    #count consecutive values
    a = df1 == 0
    b = a.cumsum(axis=1)
    c = b-b.where(~a, axis=1).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
    #replace by mask 
    return df.mask(c != 0, 'inactive_' + c.astype(str))

def f(x):
    return x.groupby(x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

def col(df):

    i = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    j = 'inactive_' + i.apply(f, axis=1).astype(str)

    df[:] = np.where(i.ne(0), df.values, j)

    return(df)
```

**Caveat**:

Performance really depend on the data.

Comment: These timings are not conclusive. It would really depend on the data. My hope is that OP's data is in a wide format with more columns than rows, so that's where you'd see better performance.

Comment: I can add timings for it too, but apply + groupby is realy slow, so I think it will be slowier too.

Comment: Indeed, but the difference would probably be less than now ;)

Comment: Hmm, this is what I thought. It might be worth coming up with a solution that first transposes the data, and then performs all these operations, and then OP can use what's best depending on their actual data.

Comment: I test it, but `In [82]: %timeit (jez(df.T).T)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.9 s per loop`

Comment: No, I don't think that'll work. Try it on the sample. A different answer may be needed.