# Python pandas cumsum with reset by value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got success/failure data on several simulations. Each simulation consists of several trials and I want a cumulative sum of the successes per simulation. Here's an example of my data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 2, 1],
                     [0, 3, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 0],
                     [1, 2, 0],
                     [1, 3, 1],
                     [2, 0, 0],
                     [2, 1, 1],
                     [2, 2, 1],
                     [2, 3, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1],
                     [0, 2, 1],
                     [0, 3, 0]],
                   columns=['simulation', 'trial', 'success'])
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436195) answer, I came up with the following code but it isn't quite working and I can't figure out why.

```
cumsum = data['success'].cumsum()
reset = -cumsum[data['trial'] == 0].diff().fillna(cumsum)
data['cumsum'] = data['success'].where(data['trial'] != 0, reset).cumsum()
```

The resulting column is `[0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 1]` but I expect `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 'simulation' & then [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) the 'success'.

```
data.groupby(data.simulation.ne(data.simulation.shift()).cumsum())['success'].cumsum()
```

or

```
data.groupby((data.simulation!=data.simulation.shift()).cumsum())['success'].cumsum()
```

Comment: The simulation number will repeat itself. Question updated to clarify.

Comment: That does the trick I think. Thank you. Would you mind explaining how that works?

Comment: With `data.simulation.ne(data.simulation.shift()).cumsum()` & `(data.simulation!=data.simulation.shift()).cumsum()` we are getting a series which corresponds to a number for each continuous value in column `simulation` (just run this & you can see the output). We then use this series to group the dataframe & `cumsum` the column `success`. If the answer helped you consider up-voting & accepting it as the answer.