# How to sum the values of a pandas column when a condition is true (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with one column called [A] and different values:

```
[A]
1
1
4
5
6
7
5
4
1
1
1
```

I would like to create another column -called B- and sum the values of A when A is > 2. If this condition is not true the result should be 0.

Finally the result of my example should be:

```
[B]
0
0
4
9
15
22
27
31
0
0
0
```

Doing this in Excel is pretty straightforward because you can sum the value of [A] to the previous [B] value. But I don’t know how to do it with Python. I have tried:

```
DF['B'] = np.where(DF['A'] > 2, DF['A'] + DF['B'].shift(-1), 0)
```

But it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also note that there is a similar question: [Cumsum reset at NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196811/cumsum-reset-at-nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is called "cumulative sum" and is implemented in pandas as `.cumsum()` (here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)).

For the `>2` condition there are multiple options, and I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but my choice is to first use `.clip(lower=2)` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)) to replace all values `<2` with `2` and then `.replace(2,0)` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)) to replace all `2`s with `0`.
(You can use only a single `.replace([1,2], 0)` if you have only non-negative integers)

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,4,5,6,7,5,4,1,1,1]})
x['B'] = x.loc[:,'A'].clip(lower=2).replace(2, 0).cumsum()
print(x)
```

output values: `B: 0, 0, 4, 9, 15, 22, 27, 31, 31, 31, 31`

#### Edit (see comments):

This is a hack to reset the cumsum whenever there is a value `<2`:

```
x['C'] = 0
for i in range(1, x.shape[0]):
    if x.loc[i, 'A'] > 2:
        z = x.loc[i-1, 'C'] if i else 0    # fix for i==0
        x.loc[i, 'C'] = z + x.loc[i, 'A']
print(x)
```

output values: `C: 0, 0, 4, 9, 15, 22, 27, 31, 0, 0, 0`

Comment: Thanks Snow, the problem with this code is that the value is not reset to 0 when ['A'] < 2. Notice that the last three values of my hypothetical ['B'] column are 0.

Comment: Do you mean a series `A` like `1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 1` should create `0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 5, 11, 0`? Sorry, did miss that in your question.

Comment: Exactly! I try to sum the current value of A to my previous stored value in B only when A > 2.

Comment: oh I see. I mean you could do it with simple manual loop, but I'll update the answer shortly. Maybe I have a cleverer idea.