counting each unique element in tensor (per row)
I got a sorted tensor like this (in pytorch):
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]]

How can I count unique elements per row to get this :
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]


Use diff and nonzero

'diff' gives me this for the first row: 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0.  I can cange it to binary and concat 1 to beginning,  So I have  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0. Then reverse~ it: 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1.  Is there a way to cumsum it to: 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 3  ?

list(map(lambda x: pd.Series(x).to_frame().groupby(0).cumcount().tolist(), your_list))

Please use variables in your example and be clear for which library you are looking for a solution. Assuming numpy and example data is stored in arr, this idea works r = np.arange(arr.shape[1]); d = np.diff(arr, prepend = arr[:, :1]).astype(bool); r - np.maximum.accumulate(r * d, axis=1)

I prefer pytorch option but will use numpy otherwise.  Thnks for your comment, I 'll see if i can make it work.

Don't loop. Among many other vectorised options, consider:
import numpy as np

groups = np.array((
    (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    (2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6),
))
yd, xd = np.diff(a=groups, axis=1).nonzero()
subtract = np.zeros_like(groups)
subtract[yd, xd] = xd
x = np.arange(groups.shape[1])
result = x - np.maximum.accumulate(subtract, axis=1)
print(result)


My understanding from your example is that the output give cumulative counts of each unique element in the tensor (per row). The following function should do the job. It may be possible to get rid of the for loop but I will leave it for someone else.
import torch

def get_cumulative_counts(tensor):
    # Create a tensor to store the cumulative counts
    counts_tensor = torch.zeros_like(tensor)

    # Perform a diff operation to find where values change
    diff = tensor[:, :-1] != tensor[:, 1:] 

    # where a new element starts
    starts = torch.cat((torch.ones(tensor.size(0), 1, dtype=torch.bool, device=tensor.device), diff), dim=1)
    
    # First element count is always 0
    for i in range(1, tensor.size(1)):
        counts_tensor[:, i] = counts_tensor[:, i - 1] + 1  # Increment count
        counts_tensor[:, i] *= ~starts[:, i]  # Reset to 0 when a new element starts

    return counts_tensor

t = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]], dtype=torch.int64)

print(get_cumulative_counts(t))

# tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])


Yes, I want it without for loop

I followed this example, it works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197211/10255067
import torch

v = torch.tensor( [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],  
                   [5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
d = ~torch.diff(v).bool()
n = torch.concat(  ( torch.zeros( v.size(0),1),d),   1).view(-1)
c=torch.cumsum(n,0)
c= torch.concat(      ( torch.tensor([0]), torch.diff( c[n==0] )     ))
n[n==0]=c.neg()
n=torch.cumsum( n,0).view(v.size())
print( n )

OUTPUT:
tensor([[0., 1., 2., 0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 1., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 1., 2.]])

